# How does numpy subtraction of vector work?

Tags: python, numpy, loops, subtraction

How does the following operation give three separate vectors inside an array? I don't understand how does it calculate the operation. Thanks in advance!!

```
    import numpy as np
    ligandPos=np.array([0.,1,2])
    ionPos=np.array([0,0,0])
    print(np.array([O - ionPos for O in ligandPos]))


    array([[0., 0., 0.],
          [1., 1., 1.],
          [2., 2., 2.]])
```

Comment: What is the intended result? For each element of `ligandPos` you're subtracting all of `ionPos`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can substitute in the values of `ligandPos` to see that this is equivalent to

```py
np.array([0 - ionPos, 1 - ionPos, 2 - ionPos])
```

`0-ionPos` is of course a vector `[0,0,0]`

`1-ionPos` is `[1,1,1]` and

`2-ionPos` is `[2,2,2]`

All of these are put together to make a 2D array